# Random function in DB2 is not evenly distributed

Tags: sql, random, db2

I find this completely astounding but the rand() function in DB2 occasionally returns a value of one.  Consider this select against a table that has about 150K rows in it:

```
select integer(rand()*10) as Num, count(*) as N
from TabWithAbout150KRows
group by integer(rand()*10)
order by 1 desc;
```

In most languages/DB's, etc, I'd expect this to return 10 rows of data, with the distribution being roughly equal.  What I actually get is **11** rows, as in the following:

```
Num       N
---   -----
10       12 
9     14871 
8     14975 
7     15213 
6     15004 
5     15196 
4     14998 
3     14916 
2     14926 
1     15081 
0     15017
```

Shocking!  In my use case I'm updating rows in a table and want to assign a random value, but it needs to be randomly distributed as opposed to the horrible situation above.

So I'm currently thinking I'll have to do the update multiple times in a loop, continuing in the 2nd...nth iterations to try again for the rows that were unlucky enough to end up with rand()=1.0

Or, I could use rand()/1.00001, but this is just silly (and not evenly distributed, either)!

Any ideas on a better way to approach this (without, for example, writing UDF's, etc, would be appreciated).

Comment: Does it ever return the exact value of 0?  If not, you can do what you want by rounding up rather than down.

Comment: Not sure why you find this "shocking" or "astounding", since your buckets are not equal. Consider that every random value between 0.9 and 0.999999... goes into the "9" bucket, but only exactly 1.0 goes into the "10" bucket.

Comment: I think it's generally accepted that the "best" way to get values in [0, 1) when you have a function that returns values in [0, 1] but otherwise meets your distribution requirements is to wrap it in your own function that loops until a value less than 1 is encountered. The loop will only very rarely need more than one iteration.

Answer (score 5):

I ran into this in 2008 using DB2/400 ...

rand() returns a floating point value with a range of [0,1] inclusive
rand() * 10 returns a floating point value in the range [0,10] inclusive

Then you convert to an integer, what you have is the following

```
[0.000, 0.9999] => 0
[1.000, 1.9999] => 1
[2.000, 2.9999] => 2
[3.000, 3.9999] => 3
[4.000, 4.9999] => 4
[5.000, 5.9999] => 5
[6.000, 6.9999] => 6
[7.000, 7.9999] => 7
[8.000, 8.9999] => 8
[9.000, 9.9999] => 9
[10.000, 10.000] => 10
```

As you can see, you'll end up with a lot less 10's than any other number.

The multiplication followed by the truncation is the issue.  Rounding instead of truncating doesn't help as there's still a smaller range of values that results in 0 or 10.

Many rand() functions return a value in the range [0,1)  (1 is excluded).  But DB2 returns [0,1].

I've used the following in DB2 to get random integers between 0 and N

```
floor(rand() * N + 0.99999)
```

I think the distribution may still be a little off from "perfect".  But it's been good enough for me.

Answer (score 2):

You want and expect ten rows but you get eleven - and one is not like expected so just filter it...

Alternative:
In the great [SQL Cookbook](http://www.db2-sql.cookbook.org) there is a lot of information around random numbers. Check it out - also `GENERATE_UNIQUE()` could be used.

Comment: The document doesn't seem to be available any longer at that link. Do you mean the book by Anthony Molinaro?

Comment: No here is another link to that book http://db2-sql-cookbook.org/

Comment: Nice! That new link looks like the "official" one anyway. You can edit your answer so that it uses the new link.